# IONIC 4 - ion-menu is not overlaping the pages

Tags: angular, ionic4, ion-menu

I have a `ion-menu` in my app but he is clicking and scrolling at the page below. The click only works in `ion-button`

I tried to use `type="overlay"` but didn't works

app.component.html

```
 <ion-app>
  <ion-menu type="overlay" id="right-menu" contentId="right-menu"         
   side="end" swipeEnabled="false" mode="md">
   <ion-content>
  <app-side-menu></app-side-menu>
   </ion-content>
  </ion-menu>
  <ion-router-outlet id="right-menu" main></ion-router-outlet>
</ion-app>
```

here is my app:
http://prntscr.com/ofg6mi

the side menu is working fine but the correct functionality its supposed to not interact with the page below.

Comment: Hi Bianca, I can't really understand what you say, can you explain a little more what the issue is?

Comment: @ChristopherKiessling Im clicking in the menu and the click is interacting with what is behind the side menu, the menu is like transparent

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using the example in the documentation. https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/menu

```html
<ion-menu side="end" type="push">
  <ion-header>
    <ion-toolbar color="danger">
      <ion-title>End Menu</ion-title>
    </ion-toolbar>
  </ion-header>
  <ion-content>
    <ion-list>
      <ion-item>Menu Item</ion-item>
      <ion-item>Menu Item</ion-item>
      <ion-item>Menu Item</ion-item>
      <ion-item>Menu Item</ion-item>
      <ion-item>Menu Item</ion-item>
    </ion-list>
  </ion-content>
</ion-menu>
```

Have you added custom css?

Comment: thanks, I used the example and the problem was just the propertie ```contentId``` lol, now its working fine. thank youu